# Problema ao submeter formulário com laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Desenvolvi um [site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZJA4.png) em `Laravel` que apresenta um problema no formulário pois ele simplesmente não funciona e não exibe nenhum erro na tela ele simplesmente não tem ação e o estranho é que `localhost` o site funciona por exemplo tem um código de erro que quando o usuário tentar submeter o formulário sem preencher os campos exibe um erro na tela no `localhost` ele aparece já na hospedagem ele não tem ação dei uma olhada no `log` e também não exibe nada mais de qualquer forma segue o `log` com o meu código.

Erro ao enviar formulário sem preencher os campos (`localhost`)

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erros não aparece na hospedagem

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]:

Endereço do site: http://agenciafront.com.br/aldeia/

***Formulário:***

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    @if (session('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {!! session('message')  !!}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'FormController@postContato', 'role' => 'form', 'class'=>'form')) !!}
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {!! Form::text('nome', null, array('placeholder'=>'Nome')) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('email', null, array('placeholder'=>'E-mail')) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('telefone', null, array('placeholder'=>'Telefone')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {!! Form::textarea('mensagem', null, array('placeholder'=>'Mensagem', 'rows'=>'5')) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit('Enviar', array('class' => 'btn btn-success'), array('id' => 'btn_submit')) !!}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

***FormController:***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Mail;
use App\Http\Requests;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('/');
    }


    public function postContato(Request $request) {
        $rules = array( 'nome' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email', 'telefone' => 'required', 'mensagem' => 'required' );
        $errors = [
            'required'    => 'O campo :attribute é obrigatório.',
            'email'    => 'Digite um email válido.',
        ];
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $errors);
        $data = array();
        $data['nome'] = $request->input("nome");
        $data['email'] = $request->input("email");
        $data['telefone'] = $request->input("telefone");
        $data['mensagem'] = $request->input("mensagem");

        if($validation->passes()) {
            Mail::send('emails.contato', $data, function($message) use($request){
                $message->from($request->input("email"), $request->input("nome"));
                $message->to('felipe@agenciafront.com.br') ->subject('contato do site');
                $message->bcc('danillo@agenciafront.com.br') ->subject('Contato do site');

            });
            return redirect('#contato')->with('message', 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
        }
        return redirect('#contato')->withErrors($validation);
    }
}
```

***Route:***

```
<?php

        Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');


    Route::get('coworking',[
        'as' => 'coworking',
        'uses' => 'CoworkingController@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('evento',[
        'as' => 'evento',
        'uses' => 'EventoController@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('sobre',[
        'as' => 'sobre',
        'uses' => 'SobreController@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('criancas',[
        'as' => 'criancas',
        'uses' => 'CriancasController@index'
    ]);

    /*Route::get('contato',[
        'as' => 'contato',
        'uses' => 'ContatoController@index'
    ]);*/

    Route::post('/', 'FormController@postContato');
```

Comment: O site me parece está configurado errado, já começa pela rota `/` que é muito estranho submeter informação assim!, `view('/')` é meio estranho também a chamada de paginas, na hora que você está enviando as informações deve está chocando com outras rotas! Quantas rotas tem no seu arquivo de rotas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado pela resposta amigo eu vou atualizar a pergunta e vou colocar todas as rotas que tenho ate o momento não são muitas

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tá la amigo todas as rotas que tenho nesse projeto adicionei na pergunta

Comment: tem uma diferença sutil em localhost e na web, não sei se percebeu! que interefere na rota. localhost está fazendo correto, já o web tem um endereço a mais é esse o motivo (`aldeia`), não aprece os erros porque o site não é redirecionado corretamente...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não amigo não percebi essa diferença oque me recomenda fazer ?

Comment: @Kirito habilita o debug em produção.

Comment: @Kirito você deve colocar no domínio realmente e testar por ele, se está testando dentro de um outra pasta esse é o problema das rotas, exemplo: `http://agenciafront.com.br/` assim é o correto, e está assim que é o errado `http://agenciafront.com.br/aldeia`, problemas rotas

Comment: aontece  seguinte esse site server também como servidor de testes andes de subirmos o site para o dominio original que seria www.aldeia.com.br por exemplo então toda a ves que fazemos um projeto novo colocamos esse site nesse subdominio que seria agenciafront.om.br/aldeia

Comment: Ai o Laravel não funciona corretamente @Kirito entendeu? esse é o motivo, coloque direto no dominio e faça o teste, se localmente funcionou, na web também funcionará ... Aparentemente seu site não tem problema, apesar de existir código redundante e desnecessário.

Comment: Entendi amigo vou dar fazer isso